# n.fn.init(644) returns with result query

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
this.searchFilter = function searchFilter(value) {
  this.$tableChildren = this.$sourceChildren.filter(":contains('" + value + "')");
};
```

So I have this function who queries a 644 rows collection of tr tags and looks if any of them have string.

The idea is that most rows have the 'hidden' class and the table only shows those elements found in the query.
I tried different methods but all return at the end a jquery collection with an added:
prevObject
:
n.fn.init(644)

Which cause problems when I loop through the collection.
In stock overflow I found only an explanation for  n.fn.init(0) which didn't really help me.

any ideas?

another problem I am facing is that the result I get doesn't contain elements with the exact search value. seems strange

Comment: share some code, the explanation alone is not helping much

Comment: what part of the code?